# youbot firmware error with youbot_HelloWorldDemo

Tags: ros, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just getting started with a new youbot. I followed the manual instructions and built a few ros programs. When I try to run them I notice a few problems. Below is a log of the output and error messages I'm getting right now:

```
youbot@kukaros1:~/applications/hello_world_demo$ sudo ./youBot_HelloWorldDemo
Info: Initializing EtherCAT on eth0 with communication thread
Info: 5 EtherCAT slaves found
Info: BaseLeftFront      Controller Type: 1610  Firmware version: 148
Warning: The youBot base motor controller have to be of type: 174 or 1632
Warning: The ethercat slave number is not available!
Info: Done.
```

A quick scan of the youbot website didn't turn up any firmware images. Any ideas of how to resolve this issue?

I also don't get anywhere unless the arm is plugged in to eth0 and that seems weird to me. Any pointers welcome

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58597/youbot-firmware-error-with-youbot_helloworlddemo/) by [speciousfool](https://answers.ros.org/users/4472/speciousfool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We hound that usb key derievered from Kuka would not function. As a workaround, following the set of instuctions here we were able to run diagnostics and do keyboard control:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rail_youbot/Tutorials/AddingAUserAndInstallingTheirLocalDrivers

I'll be interested in a similar process which works for Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [speciousfool](https://answers.ros.org/users/4472/speciousfool/) with karma: 16 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0